# Conveyor zero speed problem relay, smart relay

Tags: current, relay, control-system, dummy-load

Our company bought a bunch of outdoor conveyor belts that need to plug into each other for power and communications. The power is 4160 V and each one has a transformer to 480 V.  That power is transformed again to 120 V for control power (communications). This way, the motor starters are energized from a smart relay contact after a permissive from the downstream conveyors' smart relay contact.

I have a problem with the smart relay needing a dumb relay for some reason in the design. This relay only has its little coil for a load, tied in to a slow encoder-type roller, used as a zero speed sensor.  There are six contacts per revolution.  This zero speed roller does not work well for us in our climate outdoors, in the freezing cold or rain, and I want to replace them all with a 120 V proximity switch.

To add insult to injury, I need to add a 120 V solenoid valve coil for dust suppression on each conveyor.  There is something in the way it works that does not allow me to remove the tiny load, or add any additional load, or the smart relay contacts will open, causing a zero speed condition.  Any ideas that will help me are very much appreciated!

The smart relay is a `It is an IDEC FL1F-H12RCC`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I remove the dummy load relay and add to the control power circuit?

Comment: maybe it would be good to know what the smart relay is, how it's wired, how it's configured (I assume that smart things need configuration). Do you have manuals for these things?

Comment: It is an IDEC FL1F-H12RCC

Comment: Speak with the supplier if you want a proper answer. There's not enough information here about your problem or the design implemented to fathom anything out.